# How to debug the file with the error "Rank mismatch in array reference"?

Tags: arrays, fortran90, fortran95

I was trying to create an array using two 'do' loops.
But, some how, the way I made the array shows an error as mentioned in the title. Please be kind enough to point out the bug. I am new to Fortran.

Here's the code:

```
program energy
integer::Nx=100,Ny=10
real::kx(101),Epos(101),Eneg(101),E0=0.12,ts=0.2,tsp=2.0,ky(11),Es,Ep
Es=-(E0-4.0*ts)
Ep=(Eo-4.0*ts)
kx(1)=-0.50
do i=1,Nx
  kx(i+1)=kx(1)+i*(1.00/Nx)
end do

ky(1)=-0.50
do j=1,Ny
  ky(j+1)=ky(1)+j*(1.00/Ny)
end do

do j=1,11
  do i=1,101
```

"**The error points the line below as its source**."

```
    Epos(i,j)=sqrt(-Es*(Ep+2*ts*(cos(kx(i))+cos(ky(j)))) &
                  -(2*ts*(cos(kx(i))+cos(ky(j)))*(Ep-2*ts*(cos(kx(i))+cos(ky(j))))) &
                +(4*tsp**2)*((sin(kx(i)))**2 +(sin(ky(j)))**2))
  end do
end do

open(unit=1, file='data.dat')
do i=1,101
  write(1,*) kx(i), Epos(i,1)
end do

close(unit=1)
end program energy
```

Also, how do I plot Epos(i,j) Versus Kx(i) while keeping j or 'ky' as a parameter ?

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, let me do the editing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rank mismatch part of your question: `Epos` is declared as a one-dimensional array by

```
real::Epos(101)
```

What you need is a two-dimensional array! From your code I assume it should look like

```
real::Epos(101,11)
```

For the plotting part, I would suggest writing the result to an ASCII file (if the amount of data is not too large), and then using an external tool like GNUPLOT, Python, or Octave/Matlab for plotting the data.

Comment: Thank you Alexander for the timely help.